# Calculate the volume obtained by rotating around the y axis the circle $(x+1)^2+y^2=4$

Tags: integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

The problem I have is that the line around which the circle must be rotated cuts the circle in two parts. Any hint or help with what to do with it will be useful. Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot understand the figure, then think it like this: Consider a thin disc with radius 2, which is hinged about an axis which is in plane of disc and at a perpendicular distance of 1 from center. Now if you rotate the disc about that axis then you can imagine the desired shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as integrating the following, rotated around the black axis:

[image: Integration Shape]

You can find the volume of the red area with spherical coordinates and the green area with cylindrical coordinates.